# Populate table where columns match | TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp

This is my main table:

```
select Name, Age, Race, from Person
```

I create a temp table based on what is available in my XML file, thus the temp table might have all of the fields in my table **Person** or just 1 or just 2 in a mix order.

```
Select * from #MyTempTable = Mike, 44
```

or it can be

```
Select * from #MyTempTable = Race, Mike
```

Is it possible to populate my `Person` table with what ever values I have in my temp table?

So if the `#MyTempTable` have a column `Age` then populate the `Person` table with just the `Age` value into column `Age` in table `Person`

Comment: Which DBMS: SQL Server, Sybase ASE ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution:

You could try one of these solutions:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.columns c 
    WHERE c.object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#MyTempTable' AND c.name='Age')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MyTempTable(Name,Age)
    SELECT ... FROM ... CROSS APPLY XmlCol.nodes('/...') a(b)
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.columns c 
    WHERE c.object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#MyTempTable' AND c.name='Race')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MyTempTable(Name,Race)
    SELECT ... FROM ... CROSS APPLY XmlCol.nodes('/...') a(b)   
END
```

or

```
INSERT INTO #MyTempTable(Name,Age,Race)
SELECT ... AS Name, 
    a.b.value('(@Age)[1]','TINYINT') AS Age
    a.b.value('(@Race)[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS Race, ...
    CASE WHEN <condition for Race column> THEN value ELSE NULL AS Race   
FROM ... CROSS APPLY XmlCol.nodes('/...') a(b)
```

Note 1: Because reading data from `sys.columns` system view requires special rights (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)) the simplest solution is the second solution.

Note 2: Starting from SQL Server 2008 you could use [SPARSE columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to reduce the storage size for those columns that have columns with many NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning the XML into a query to create a temp table ([SQL Server shred XML to temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463775/sql-server-shred-xml-to-temp-table)).  Then you can have separate update statements for Age and Race, for example:

```
UPDATE Person
SET Age = Imported.Age
FROM Person
   INNER JOIN Imported ON Imported.Name = Person.Name
WHERE Imported.Age IS NOT NULL
```

And so on.